# How to count the no of occurrences of a word in a text file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, find-occurrences

I would like to know how it would be possible to 
1) Get a txt file as an input.
2) count the no of times a word or words occur! eg say i want to count the no of times good , bad are found in a text file and print it!
how would i do this using RUBY?

Comment: What's your effort on this problem?

Comment: I am new to ruby , I am unable to understand how using (gets) I can get more than one line! I have used .include to match and realize that it matches only the first instance of one of the words.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
word_count = {}

File.open("test.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    words = line.split(' ').each do |word|
      word_count[word] += 1 if word_count.has_key? word
      word_count[word] = 1 if not word_count.has_key? word
    end
  end
end

puts word_count
```

You could also chuck a check in there to see if it matches a certain word you are looking for or check if they exist in a hash of multiple words you are looking for if you're not interested in everything